# What does this pistol symbol mean in Raid Mode?

Tags: resident-evil-revelations

In Raid Mode there is this symbol with pistol and some number next to it (for me it's always 0), see screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What does it mean?

I play on PS4 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon is a "co-op" participation counter.

Quoting from [GameFAQs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps3/700994-resident-evil-revelations/answers/352125-blue-gun-symbol):

> "If I recall correctly, it's a counter for how many times you've played Co-op. Each Co-op session will increase it by one point."

[Source 2](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/700996-resident-evil-revelations/66391203), 
[Source 3](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/700996-resident-evil-revelations/66295348)

Comment: damn, now everyone knows I have no friends :(